# Copy and Pasting Special Specific Columns to a different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vb.net

i have tons of information i wanted to copy and paste to a working sheet. i only wanted specific columns. however when run this code it's giving me this error on this part .Range(MyCopyRange).Copy. i just modified the code i got from the site.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim LR As Long, MyCopyRange As Variant, MyPasteRange As Variant, X As Long

Me.UsedRange.Offset(17).ClearContents

With Sheets("CrystalReportViewer")
.AutoFilterMode = False
LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MyCopyRange = Array("R1:R" & LR, "S1:S" & LR, "T1:T" & LR, "U1:U" & LR, "V1:V" & LR, "W1:W" & LR, "X1:X" & LR) 'Put ranges in an array
MyPasteRange = Array("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2")


If LR > 1 Then
    For X = LBound(MyCopyRange) To UBound(MyCopyRange) 'Loop the array copying and pasting based on element in the array
        .Range(MyCopyRange).Copy
        Sheets("Master_File").Range(MyPasteRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next

End If
.AutoFilterMode = False

 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: What error message?

Comment: run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error